# convert a Nested Json to a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a json with nested feilds and dates feilds that i'd like to concatenate :

```
root
 |-- MODEL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- START_Time: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WEIGHT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REGISTED: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TOTAL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SCHEDULED: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: long (nullable = true)
 |-- PACKAGE: string (nullable = true)
```

objective is to get a result more like :

```
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+
|MODEL    |   START_Time     | WEIGHT   |REGISTED         |TOTAL    |SCHEDULED        |   
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+
|.........| yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss| WEIGHT   |yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss|TOTAL    |yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss|
```

where yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss are the conactenation of: day, hour, minute.... in the json

```
|-- example: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
```

i have tried explode function may be didn't use it as it should but didn't work
can anyone inspire me for a solution
Thank you

Comment: You're asking the same question, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511485/3441510

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in below simple steps.

1. Lets we have the data as below in the data.json file

> {"MODEL": "abc", "CODE": "CODE1", "START_Time": {"day": "05", "hour": "08", "minute": "30", "month": "08", "second": "30", "year": "21"}, "WEIGHT": "231", "REGISTED": {"day": "05", "hour": "08", "minute": "30", "month": "08", "second": "30", "year": "21"}, "TOTAL": "1", "SCHEDULED": {"day": "05", "hour": "08", "minute": "30", "month": "08", "second": "30", "year": "21"},"PACKAGE": "CAR"}

This data has the same schema as you shared.

2. Read this json file in pyspark as below.

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *

   df = spark.read.json('data.json')
   ```
3. Now you can read the nested values and modify the column values as below.

   ```
   df.withColumn('START_Time', concat(col('START_Time.year'), lit('-'), col('START_Time.month'), lit('-'), col('START_Time.day'), lit('-'), col('START_Time.hour'), lit('-'), col('START_Time.minute'), lit('-'), col('START_Time.second'))).withColumn('REGISTED',concat(col('REGISTED.year'), lit('-'), col('REGISTED.month'), lit('-'), col('REGISTED.day'), lit('-'), col('REGISTED.hour'), lit('-'), col('REGISTED.minute'), lit('-'), col('REGISTED.second'))).withColumn('SCHEDULED',concat(col('SCHEDULED.year'), lit('-'), col('SCHEDULED.month'), lit('-'), col('SCHEDULED.day'), lit('-'), col('SCHEDULED.hour'), lit('-'), col('SCHEDULED.minute'), lit('-'), col('SCHEDULED.second'))).show()
   ```

The output would be

| CODE | MODEL | PACKAGE | REGISTED | SCHEDULED | START_Time | TOTAL | WEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE1 | abc | CAR | 21-08-05-08-30-30 | 21-08-05-08-30-30 | 21-08-05-08-30-30 | 1 | 231 |