# explode Nested Values of (year,month,day, hours,minute,second) to a date time type in one field in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm Trying to convert the nested Fields into one Field of DATETIME type when i use explode function i get an error : cannot resolve 'explode(`START_Time`)' due to data type mismatch

data i have :

```
 |-- MODEL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- START_Time: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WEIGHT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REGISTRED: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TOTAL: string (nullable = true)
```

Result i'm looking to have :
with START_TIME and REGISTRED as DATE type

```
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|MODEL    |   START_Time     | WEIGHT   |REGISTED         |TOTAL    |
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|.........| yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss| WEIGHT   |yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss|TOTAL    |
```

i have tried :

df.withColumn('START_Time', concat(col('START_Time.year'), lit('-'), .....)

but when there  are empty values in the nested fiels it gets (-----)  in
and it gets me :

```
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|MODEL    |   START_Time     | WEIGHT   |REGISTED         |TOTAL    |
+---------+------------------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|value    | -----            | value    | -----           |value    |
```

Answer (score 0):

After concatenating, you can just cast the entire column to `timestamp` type, Spark will handle the missing (and invalid) data for you and return `null` instead

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('raw_string_date', F
        .concat(
            F.col('START_TIME.year'),
            F.lit('-'),
            F.col('START_TIME.month'),
            F.lit('-'),
            F.col('START_TIME.day'),
            F.lit(' '),
            F.col('START_TIME.hour'),
            F.lit(':'),
            F.col('START_TIME.minute'),
            F.lit(':'),
            F.col('START_TIME.second'),
        )
    )
    .withColumn('date_type', F.col('raw_string_date').cast('timestamp'))
    .show(10, False)
)

# +------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+
# |START_TIME                          |raw_string_date|date_type          |
# +------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+
# |{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2021}               |2021-4-1 2:3:5 |2021-04-01 02:03:05|
# |{, , , , , }                        |-- ::          |null               |
# |{null, null, null, null, null, null}|null           |null               |
# +------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you , it did work and clean and clear

Comment: You're welcome! If it answered your question, please accept the answer, that would help others as welll